# Proving Least Lower Bound As The Limit

Tags: calculus

Suppose that there is a function $f(x)$which is bounded and increasing on the interval $(c, c+a)$ for some $a>0$,and let $L$ be the least lower bound of $f(x)$ on the given interval  then prove that $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$ 
$$$$As $L$ is the least lower bound of $f(x)$ then if for some $x_0$ in the interval $(c, c+a)$ , $f(x_0)=L$ and as $f(x)$ is an increasing function, so for all $c<x<x_0$ we have $L \leq f(x) \leq f(x_0)=L$ and hence for all $c<x<x_0$ we have $f(x)=L$ and hence $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$. Now suppose there is no $x$ in the interval $(c, c+a)$ such that $f(x)=L$ then as $L$ is the least lower Bound of $f(x)$ for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some value of $f(x)$ in the interval $(L, L+\epsilon)$ say $y_0$ for some $x_1$ in the interval $(c, c+a)$ then again as $f(x)$ is an increasing function so for all $c<x<x_1$ we have.  $$L \leq f(x) \leq f(x_1)<L+ \epsilon $$ and hence we have $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$

Comment: Seems correct, but the term least lower bound is strange. Maybe you mean maximum lower bound?